# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str? Hangman

Tags: python

The problem starts on this part of the code when I want to replace an underscore from the `w` list with he found a letter from the `myword` string, I don't want to look up the whole hangman solution though! Any suggestions?

```py
while t == 0:
    for i in myword:
        if guess == i:
            t = 1
            w[i] = i
            print(w)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is a single character from the string, so `w[i]` won't work -- as the error states, you can't use a string to slice another string.

Instead, you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get both the letter and the letter's index at the same time:

```
while t == 0:
    for idx, letter in enumerate(myword):
        if guess == letter:
            t = 1
            w[idx] = letter
            print(w)
```

Comment: This is good. Also, to avoid confusion, the variable `t` could be changed to be a boolean type, True | False. This way the loop runs while the variable t is True.

Comment: Thank you so much and for answering so quick! <3 that was a big help understanding

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are iterating over a string `myword`, your `i` is actually a letter, so `i` is a string. So you could have index if this letter with `enumerate` without any runtime overhead (like getting an index of the letter with `myword.index(letter)`):

```py
while t == 0:
    for index, letter in enumerate(myword):
        if guess == letter:
            t = 1
            w[index] = letter
            print(w)
```

2. You don't need a `while` loop to stop iteration. There is a keyword `break` exactly for this case:

```py
for index, letter in enumerate(myword):
    if guess == letter:
        w[index] = letter
        print(w)  # this will print w on each finding the guess
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in the answer above/below, you can use `enumerate` to access each element aligned with its index in the string.

But if you are not familiar with `enumerate`, you can use [`str.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20index#str.index):

```
while t == 0:
    for i in myword:
        if guess == i:
            t = 1
            w[myword.index(i)] = i
            print(w)
```

Comment: Solution with `str.index()` is O(n2). enumerate is O(n)

Comment: Yeah, I know `enumerate` is better :)